# Python reading the first entry of a paranthesis in a series of paranthesis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have thousands of lines of the following sample in a csv file. The header of the file is as follows:

**File Hearder:**

> field1, field2, field3, field4

**Sample Data:**

> field1, field2, 1, "[('entryA', 'typeA'), ('entryB', 'typeB'), ('entryC', 'typeC'),
> ('entryD', 'typeD')]"

My question is how to extract field3 and pair it with the first entry of each parenthesis and put it in the following format?

**What I need:**

> {
> "id": "field3",
> "entries" : ["entryA", "entryB", "entryC", "entryD"]
> }

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

id = df['field3']
entries = df['field4']

for row in entries:
    result = entries.str.findall("(?<=\(').*?(?=',)")
```

**Current output:**

The current Regex works but, I just noticed that I have special symbols like '(' in my entries which affects the matched results (unwanted matches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better way.

```
import ast
s = ast.literal_eval(s)
entries = [a[0] for a in s]
```

### Followup

pandas is not helping you.  Pre-process the data and convert to pandas afterward.  It looked like all you wanted is the third field and the expanded fourth field, so that's all I kept.

```
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd

headers = []
data = []
for row in csv.reader(open('file.csv')):
    if not headers:
        headers = row
    else:
        entries = [a[0] for a in ast.literal_eval(row[3]))
        data.append( [row[2], entries] )

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','entries'])
```

Comment: A DataFrame containing strings?  Then you could do this conversion BEFORE converting to a DataFrame.  You should modify your question to show exactly what you have, and exactly what you're expecting.

Comment: Did you read my answer at all?  Do you see any regular expressions in there?

Comment: You need to decide what you want.  Do you want all of those names as a single field?  What's the point?  What are you going to do with this data when you have it?  Why use pandas at all?

Comment: Yes, I showed exactly in the section "what I need" in my question. I know that it is weird but I need this format to feed the generated data to a Python API for further tasks. It doesn't have to be with Pandas. I only need to recreate the following format.                  {
    "id": "field3",
    "entries" : ["entryA", "entryB", "entryC", "entryD"]
}

Comment: Well, sort of.  You showed an example dictionary, not an example DataFrame.  I've modified the code to produce a dataframe with two columns: `id` and `entries`.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `re`, use `ast.literal_eval`

```py
>>> s = "[('entryA', 'typeA'), ('entryB', 'typeB'), ('entryC', 'typeC'), ('entryD', 'typeD')]"
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(s)
[('entryA', 'typeA'), ('entryB', 'typeB'), ('entryC', 'typeC'), ('entryD', 'typeD')]
>>> out = [i[0] for i in literal_eval(s)]
>>> out
['entryA', 'entryB', 'entryC', 'entryD']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use lookahead and lookbehind regexs to do the following

```py
s = "[('entryA', 'typeA'), ('entryB', 'typeB'), ('entryC', 'typeC'), ('entryD', 'typeD')]"
result = re.findall("(?<=\(').*?(?=',)", s)

print("\"entries\":",result)
```

Lookahead: `(?=EXPR)` looks what is directly ahead the element.
Lookbehind: `(?<=EXPR)` looks what is directly behind the element.

---

New version:

```py
result = df.field4.str.extractall("((?<=\(').*?(?=',))").to_numpy().reshape(2, 4)
```

Which gives(added an extra row to for testing purpose)

```py
array([['entryA', 'entryB', 'entryC', 'entryD'],
       ['entryA1', 'entryB1', 'entryC1', 'entryD1']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot. While your suggested Regex works, I just noticed that I have special symbols like '(' in my entries which affects the matched results (unwanted matches). Do you think of any way that this could be solved? It doesn't have to be Regex. I tried the other two answers, but couldn't apply them into my problem.

Comment: @Chelsea-fc please add those in the sample data, to test. Also you can delete your old comments to make the conversation less clustered as they are not relevant any more.